# C language : how to interpret this #define?

Tags: c, pointers, c-preprocessor

I've found this snippet on a website :

```
#define DISPLAY_CR  (*(volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000000) 
DISPLAY_CR = somevalue;
```

that is supposed to describe DISPLAY_CR as a volatile unsigned int pointer to the adress 0x4000000

What I don't understand is why :

- the double parenthesis imbrication ?
- the two stars using (why two stars and not only one ?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extra parentheses are standard practice in macros.  Macros are expanded in copy-and-paste fashion, so without the parentheses, the [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) may be altered depending on the context.

Ignoring the extra parentheses, your code expands to:

```
*(volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000000 = somevalue;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
volatile unsigned int *p = 0x4000000; // Treat this as the address of a volatile unsigned int
*p = somevalue; // Write to that address
```

which hopefully should be clearer.

Comment: Thank you :) And what about the two stars : why two stars ?

Answer (score 2):

The extra parenthesis are to stop the macro from being corrupted by surrounding tokens.
the 'stars' are use to cast the address to a pointer, then dereference it, to get the value at its address

Answer (score 2):

You've got

- `0x4000000` - address 0x4000000
- `(volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000000` - cast to a volatile pointer
- `* (volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000000` - dereference the pointer to make an lvalue
- `(*(volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000000)` - wrap in an extra set of brackets so that `DISPLAY_CR` is effectively a single token - you won't get into operator precedence problems etc. around it

Comment: Thank you for this usefull step-by-step explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses around the whole expression are important for all macros, and critical with a macro like the one listed.

If someone were to write, say:

```
int foo = DISPLAY_CR++;
```

and there were no parentheses enclosing the macro, that would parse as:

```
int foo = *(volatile unsigned int *)(0x4000000++);
```

which has an altogether different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

This macro does not describe `DISPLAY_CR` as a volatile unsigned int pointer to the address `0x4000000`. It describes `DISPLAY_CR` as an unsigned integer *value* located at the `0x4000000`, most likely, a hardware-specific register.

The reason you need `volatile` is to prevent the compiler from "optimizing" multiple writes to a hardware register. For example, if you need to signal something to the hardware by setting the value to 1 and then clearing it, you could write

```
DISPLAY_CR = 1;
DISPLAY_CR = 0;
```

Without `volatile` the compiler could drop the first assignment as insignificant; `volatile` prevents it from doing so.

Comment: Thank you for the volatile "use-case" :)

Answer (score 0):

The star inside means that the type is pointer to unsigned int. The outer star dereferents the pointer to a memory unit it points to.

Answer (score 0):

OK, lets break this down.

Obviously, `0x4000000` is a number, which we want to use to specify a specific memory address (hopefully there's something important there).

Now, `(volatile unsigned int *)` is a *cast*, which means it tell the compiler that to force the type of the argument to the specified type (which is pointer to an unsigned integer, volatile).

Finally, `*` is the dereferencing operator. It means we want to access the value stored in that address.

The extra parentheses are just good style when using macros - C programmers are especially defensive with them, since the operator precedence rules are a bit confusing.